# Testing custom pipes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, formatting, jasmine

I am trying to write some basic tests for my custom pipe, but being new to Jasmine and Angular pipes I am having some difficulty.  Here is my pipe:

decimal-format-pipe.js

```
import { Pipe , PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myDecimalFormatingPipe'
})

export class MyDecimalFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {};

    transform(value: any) {
        if (value || value === 0) {
            value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.2-2');
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this 'custom' pipe simply implements the decimal pipe transform() for now, but that will change in the future.

Here is my spec:

```
import { MyDecimalFormatPipe } from './my-decimal-format.pipe';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

describe('MyDecimalFormatPipe', () => {

    let pipe: MyDecimalFormatPipe;
    let decimalPipe: DecimalPipe;
    let inputValue: any = '2.1111';

    beforeEach( () => {
        decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe(inputValue);
        myPipe = new MyDecimalFormatPipe(decimalPipe);
    });

    it('pipe is defined', () => {
        expect(pipe instanceof MyDecimalFormatPipe).toBeTruthy();
    });

    describe('transform ', () => {
        it('should return correct value type ', () => {

            spyOn(decimalPipe, 'transform').and.callThrough();

            decimalPipe.transform(inputValue, '1.2-2');

            expect(decimalPipe.transform).toEqual('2.11');
        });
    });
});
```

My first spec passes but for the transform() test it fails and I get the

```
error: 
 RangeError: Invalid language tag: 2.1111
          at new NumberFormat (native)
          at Function.NumberFormatter.format (
```

I cannot recall the last time I have seen this error.  What does 'invalid language tag' refer to?  What is it about this spec that is making it break?

Comment: I believe the input value is parsed as a date or whatever thing that makes it freak out. Did you try using number values ? Does that change anything ? The test seems correct

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'use number values'?  I am currently passing a string in the inputValue to transform() because the JSON coming from the backend will have the numbers as strings....Should I try to pass it a number..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing `y_vyshnevska`'s answer, there are several points that are to be noted :

- You need to use `decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe('arab');` to tell the `DecimalPipe` constructor to use the arabic number format (in your case).
- From the official documentation, I believe you don't need to use a spy for this test (https://angular.io/guide/testing#pipes), but simply getting the returned result from your pipe should be enough.

**Edited parts** :

```
beforeEach(() => {
  decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe('arab');
  pipe = new MyDecimalFormatPipe(decimalPipe);
});

...

it('should return correct value type ', () => {
  // spyOn(pipe, 'transform').and.callThrough();
  const result = pipe.transform(inputValue);
  expect(result).toEqual('2.11');
});
...
```

---

**N.B:** One funny thing I could witness, is that with the Headless chrome the test would pass as the result is correct (**2.11**); but in my chrome browser the test would fail saying the result is incorrect (**2,11**). I guess this is due to the browser settings, but I didn't expect that either :-)

Comment: Aha! What a wonderful answer.  I do not understand why when spyOn.and.callThrough() was removed it returned the expected result, but otherwise it did not.  As far as I understand spyOn simply monitors the output and arguments...why would it change the result?

Comment: You should read this : https://hatoum.com/blog/2016/11/12/jasmine-unit-testing-dont-forget-to-callthrough. It explains pretty well why it is needed in some cases, but here you actually don't need it at all since you can directly call the pipe result !

Comment: Ok, right, maybe I am missing something.  As in the Jasmine docs, callThrough() defers to the actual implementation (not a stub).  My conclusion from this is that `spyOn(decimalPipe, 'transform').and.callThrough();` should be expected to return the same result as simply calling the transform() method as we did in your implementation.  Yet, my implementation fails while your passes...

Comment: Hum, seems pretty weird indeed... what is the log for `decimalPipe.transform` in your case ?

Answer (score 2):

> What does 'invalid language tag' refer to?

[The DecimalPipe constructor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.6/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L90)  has an injected string argument for locale, which is used for [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) construction [deeper](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.6/packages/common/src/pipes/intl.ts#L36). Try
 `new Intl.NumberFormat('1.222').format(1.2222)` in browser console, you will see your error.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't get this one